# Facebook Javascript SDK - reauthentication - closing window still authenticates the user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently trying to implement the very basic reauthentication example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/, and have the popup generating, and have got the authResponse object successfully.

However, I have noticed that, if I close the popup window that appears, I am still getting the authResponse object, as if the re-auth was successful, and therefore my error code is not running.

It was my impression that, if the user did not submit any of the LoginDialog forms, there would be no authResponse as part of the response object, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I am regenerating a new `auth_nonce` with each login request, but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've seen that other people have asked this question before (4 years ago in one case) but haven't found a verified answer - does anyone have any kind of solution for this?

Many thanks

Comment: I filed a bug report about this 4 years ago, they said it was resolved ... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/248632218597467/

Comment: Ha, excellent!  Well, just commented on that post so let's see what happens.  Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI if anyone comes across this, I logged the issue again with Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/466922970358399/) and can confirm that, today at least, the issue has been fixed